# Record Name field in DNS responce

Tags: dns

I just read about DNS protocol, and found, that the *name field* can be writen in two ways:

1. `lenght of the next label` `the label` `lenght of the next label` `the label` ... `zero-byte`
2. `pointer to the previous name field`

Next is the [original article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197470%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) fragment:

> The Resource Record Name field is encoded in the same way as the
> Question Name field unless the name is already present elsewhere in
> the DNS message, in which case a 2-byte field is used in place of a
> length-value encoded name and acts as a pointer to the name that is
> already present.

So, my question is, how can I determine the first or the second way is using in a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first two bits are ones.  This allows a pointer to be distinguished
>   from a label, since the label must begin with two zero bits because
>   labels are restricted to 63 octets or less.

See the chapter "4.1.4. Message compression" in [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt)

Comment: imho it is always better to go straight to the source (meaning RFCs) for internet protocols. 3rd party descriptions such as the one from technet might be inaccurate.